# Why am I getting a blank screen?

Tags: swift3, dropbox-api, xcode8-beta2, swiftydropbox

I'm following [this tutorial on Github](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox) to learn how to use SwiftyDropbox, and I've followed the steps to the point where I should be able to run the app, and I log into Dropbox. However, when I run the app on my phone, I just get a blank screen. Can someone help me figure out why?

Here's the code for my AppDelegate

[image]

The ViewController

[image]

the plist

[image]

and the podfile

[image]

Comment: You're surrounding your app key with angle brackets in the call to `setupWithAppKey`. It should be just string of the app key itself, no brackets.

Comment: Also, are you getting any error/output in the console?

Comment: @Greg I'm getting an error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" on the line "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {"

Comment: It looks like you accepted and answer here and posted the other error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389361/what-can-i-do-to-fix-the-error-thread-1-signal-sigabrt so I'll take a look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial isn't exhaustive of every step you need to take to run the app. If you download the whole project and open TestSwifty > TestSwifty_iOS > TestSwifty_iOS.xcworkspace, you'll see in the Main.storyboard that there are buttons, which are connected to code.