# What can I do to fix the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"?

Tags: swift3, ios10, dropbox-api, xcode8-beta2, swiftydropbox

I'm following [this tutorial on Github](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox) to try and learn how to use SwiftyDropbox, but I've run into this error

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyDropbox

@UIApplicationMain
```

> > class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        DropboxClientsManager.setupWithAppKey("qcvovib4h1mn0zd")
        return true
    }
```

Here's what I'm getting in the output box

```
2016-12-29 15:41:23.576964 GaethrExample[1164:292818] -[GaethrExample.ViewController launchDropbox:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102809370
2016-12-29 15:41:23.583475 GaethrExample[1164:292818] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GaethrExample.ViewController launchDropbox:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102809370'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18b6a61c0 0x18a0e055c 0x18b6ad278 0x18b6aa278 0x18b5a459c 0x191536484 0x191536404 0x1915208b8 0x191535cf0 0x191535818 0x191530a60 0x19150152c 0x19f54953c 0x191ceea54 0x191ce84bc 0x18b654278 0x18b653bc0 0x18b6517c0 0x18b580048 0x18d006198 0x19156c2fc 0x191567034 0x1000d5b58 0x18a5645b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here's my ViewController code

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyDropbox


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var launchDropbox: UIButton!

    @IBAction func launchDropboxPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared, controller: self,
                                                      openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in
                                                        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

What do I need to do to fix the error?

Comment: Is that the the full error/output you're getting? I would imagine you'd get more than that, so please share anything else you're getting, e.g., in the output console.

Comment: @Greg I added the output. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error says your `ViewController` object doesn't have a `launchDropbox:` method.  Can you show some details about where you have that defined or where you're calling it?

Comment: @PhillipMills I added the ViewController code

Comment: Check your connection from the button.  Is it pointing to `launchDropboxPressed` (it should be)?  Something thinks it should call your outlet as if it were a function.

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, I just reconnected it

Comment: @Greg Thoughts?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/issues/143 ] Apologies, this is outside my area of expertise.